# Using "afconvert" to convert .flac to Apple Lossless - files are too large

Tags: mac, flac

I have a .flac file that I need to convert to Apple Lossless.
I've tried 2 settings:

```
afconvert -f m4af -d alac track.flac -o track.m4a
afconvert -f AIFF -d BEI32 track.flac -o track.aiff
```

The problem is that both options are spitting out a file that's 120-150 MB, while the original is 47 MB.

I know that AIFF will be heavy, but I've bought some AIFF songs on Beatport and they are like 60-80 MB max.

What else could I try?

Comment: Have you tried `ffmpeg`?  The command would be `ffmpeg -i input.flac output.aiff`. This can be obtained as [a binary](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or from MacPorts and Homebrew.

Comment: It also gives huge files.

Comment: If I remember correctly, AIFF will be much larger than FLAC because it is uncompressed versus compressed, respectively. I don’t use AIFF due to it’s limitation to Apple devices so my experience is limited.

Comment: I've no clue how to use afconvert, but Apple Lossless is not .aiff, it's m4a but with a different codec. Should be about the same size as a flac. Use [XLD](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xld/) it's simpler (once you figure out you have to keep the prefs open to change settings;)